# How can I trim a specific character off the start & end of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, trim

How can I remove a specific character, a double-quote (`"`), appearing any number of times, from the start and end of a string?

I had a look at [`string.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), which trims any whitespace characters, but it's not possible to provide an optional argument with `"` as the needle to search for.

Comment: possibly adapt this shim for trim to shave what you crave  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @Paul That was for the days when there was no native `string.trim()` function. This exists now, but it's only for whitespace.

Comment: Adapting `this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` means changing the `\s+` to `"+` ... which then matches your answer, actually.  So now we have some confirmation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use RegEx to easily conquer this problem:

```
myString = myString.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, '');
```

You can substitute the `"` with any character (be careful, [some characters need to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/javascript-regexp-list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-c)).

Here's [a demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RL8y3/1/).

---

An explanation of the regular expression:

`/` - start RegEx (`/`)

`^"+` - match the start of the line (`^`) followed by a quote (`"`) 1 or more times (`+`)

`|` - or

`"+$` - match a quote (`"`) 1 or more times (`+`) followed by the end of the line (`$`)

`/` - end RegEx (`/`)

`g` - "global" match, i.e. replace all

Comment: Great answer, but I take offence to your use of the term "easily" :)