# What characters need to be escaped to be interpreted literally in a regular expression capture group?

Tags: regex

If I want to capture a pipe character `|` in the capture group of a regular expression then it needs to be backslash escaped so it isn't interpreted as an alternator.

```
(and\|or) matches the string "and|or"
(and|or) matches the strings "and" and "or"
```

What other characters need to be escaped inside a capture group in order to be interpreted literally? Is there a comprehensive list of these characters?

Comment: a capture group doesn't change what you must escape. In general all characters that have a special meaning in a regular expression must be escaped to be used as literal. However there are some exceptions depending of the flavour and the context. You can see an example for square brackets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-to-regex

Comment: What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @kevlar1818 I'm not sure if it's really necessary to know for the question, but since you ask, I'm dynamically creating a regex and I need to escape characters that are supplied as input if they need to be interpreted literally.

Comment: @CoryKlein you could just put each character into its own character set, which prevents the need to escape

Comment: What programming language and/or regex library are you using? There will probably be a function to escape whatever needs escaping in this particular regex dialect, for example the Java [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) or perl [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Comment: @IanRoberts I'm using QRegExp. From what I can tell, it doesn't provide such functionality.