# Browser not handling quote parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1449/

The alert does not fire correctly as there are quotes within the text :

```
<input type="button" value="test" />

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  "test" for equities.");   
});

function s(value){
 alert(value)   
}
```

So if I use instead

```
<input type="button" value="test" />

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  test for equities.");   
});

function s(value){
 alert(value)   
}
```

The quotes within the String in first example is causing the issue. Are there other characters I should be aware of which can cause similar issue ?

I think this question is related to [List of all characters that should be escaped before put in to RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-to-regex/5105195#5105195) but in my case I am referring to a javascript String instead of regex

Comment: Note that the attribute value inside the selector sould be surrounded with quotes like `$('input[type="button"]')` instead of `$('input[type=button]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape it using slash ([other escape characters too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5105195/1671639) - complete list of character that has to be escaped)

```
s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  \"test\" for equities.");
```

Also you can have it within single quotes.

```
s('test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  "test" for equities.');
```

Using double quotes within single quotes and vice versa doesn't need to be escaped.
**Example:**
1. " test 'test' "
2. ' test "test" '

Comment: @blue-sky ok I understood.. then it is [special character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx).. the answer for your 2nd question is `slash`.. try like `console.log("\");\\nothing will be printed`, then escape it using `"\\"`  ASIK that it.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quote by using the slash:

```
s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  \"test\" for equities.");
```

Or, use a single quote:

```
s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  'test' for equities.");
```

Or, this:

```
s('test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  "test" for equities.');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1456/)

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
s('test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  "test" for equities.');
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M9b2D/)

Answer (score 1):

You simply miss the escape char "\".

Parser read the first " still the next thinking that the string is ended. Then read "test" and reports:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

So you must specify that your " is part of the string.

So:

```
s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  \"test\" for equities.");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace outer double quotes with single quotes :

```
  $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  'test' for equities.");   
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1454/)**

Comment: You can use escape chars too '\'

Comment: @Tyranicangel: why when user have alternative to use other quotes.

Comment: I just provided an alternative.

Comment: @Tyranicangel: i don't see any point in making things complicated when there are simple ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1455/

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    test=20;
 s("test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  "+test+" for equities.");   
});

function s(value1){
 alert(value1)   
}
```

assuming test is variable

Answer (score 0):

Quotes should be escaped in javascript either by combination of single and double quotes or by using a `\` to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

you should write in this way
declare html code like

```
<input type="button" value="test" />
```

and write jQuery like

```
 $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
         alert($(this).val());
         var tmp = "test - <b>test</b> <b>est - test:  "+$(this).val()+" for equities.";
         s(tmp);   
        });

        function s(value){
         alert(value);  
        }
```

don't forget ; after alert(value);

Comment: FYI: it is not mandatory to use semi-colon `;` for each statements here is JS.