# Escaping a Javascript string, Unterminated character class error

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I keep getting the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /$_POST['/: Unterminated character class
```

I searched a few threads and they all pointed me to the fact the at I am not properly escaping the string.
I loaded a php file into a javascript var as a string , then I search through it for the following, but I have tried escaping to no success.

according to [List of all characters that should be escaped before put in to RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-to-regex)

These are all the characters that need escaping I believe.

```
. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -
```

and here are the code snipets that are failing me. (This is the clean code everything needs escaping)

```
var n = data.search("$_POST['");
n = res.search("'];");
n = data.search("//hurdle{"); 
n = res.search("}");
```

If someone could show me how to properly do this, it would be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How are you attempting to escape these characters? With a \?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar and brackets: `\$`, `\[` and `\]`

For example:

```
arrayOfMatches = yourString.match(/\$_POST\['/g);
```

Comment: How about the  ' , and the $? I try escaping those as well but I still get errors.

Comment: The `g` is for getting all the matches in one go. That's just one example, there are a number of JS regex methods, e.g. `exec`. Here is [a decent summary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: Thank you! now I'm running into a range error, haha the love of debugging.

Comment: edit: I will add the code to the main section in a second I am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

For first expression

```
data.search(/\$_POST\['/)
```