# Javascript email regex

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I've come across a description of a decent email regex.

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

But I would also like to include some punctuation characters into the first part of the email whilst retaining the rest of the functionality (such as no repeated .)

The best I have come up with so far is:

```
([\/!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~]*\w+)([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,40})+$
```

But this will not allow punctuation at the end of the first part of the email.

I find regex so confusing, does anyone know how to properly implement this?

Example:

```
Yes email@domain.com
Yes firstname.lastname@domain.com
Yes email@subdomain.domain.com
Yes firstname+lastname@domain.com
Yes email@123.123.123.123
Yes email@[123.123.123.123]
Yes "email"@domain.com
Yes 1234567890@domain.com
Yes email@domain-one.com
Yes _______@domain.com
Yes email@domain.name
Yes email@domain.co.jp
Yes firstname-lastname@domain.com
No  plainaddress
No  #@%^%#$@#$@#.com
No  @domain.com
No  Joe Smith <email@domain.com>
No  email@domain@domain.com
No  .email@domain.com
No  email.@domain.com
No  email..email@domain.com
No  あいうえお@domain.com
No  email@domain.com (Joe Smith)
No  email@domain
No  email@-domain.com
No  email@domain.web
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs?

Comment: Best tip I can give is: start small (just the basics) with regex and expand from there. This keeps you in control of what you're doing instead of trial error like approach ☺

Comment: Take a look at this thread [Validate email address in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you want generic email validation regexp? If so, this question duplicate - see link in comment above. Or do you want to allow only some specific emails?

Comment: No I've got a specific type of regex in mind. There are a lot of different email regex but this is one to fit a specific set of requirements.

Comment: Why is `email@domain.web` invalid?

Comment: Is there a reason why my answer does not fulfill your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

This is my closest attempt now, I think it is roughly correct

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&‘*\=\+\/\?^{|}~]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&‘*\=\+\/\?^{|}~]+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,50})+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `\w` with its equivalent `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and escape all the special characters from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-to-regex).

try this:-

```
/^[\/\!#\$\%&'\*\+\-\=\?\^_`\{\|\}~A-Za-z0-9]+[\.-]?[\/\!#\$\%&'\*\+\-\=\?\^_`\{\|\}~A-Za-z0-9]*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,40})+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\"]+)([\_\.\-\+{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\"\_]+)\@([a-zA-Z0-9\[]+)([\-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?([\.])([a-zA-Z0-9\.\]]+)
```

Jack, the expression I have mentioned above will provide the solution for this problem. This will give the desired results according to the question.