# Firefox error: Unable to check input because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression

Tags: regex, html, firefox, escaping

I'm using regex pattern matching for HTML5 form validation.   The latest version of Firefox gives me an error.  I only started seeing this in Firefox 46.  I don't think this was a problem in earlier Firefox versions.

> Unable to check `<input pattern='[\@\%]'>` because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression

Caused by this very simple test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <form>
    <input pattern="[\@\%]">
  </form>
</html>
```

Why is escaping these characters considered an error? I've always escaped everything in my regular expressions that isn't a number or a letter.   I've never had anything complain this type of escaped character except this version of Firefox.

When I learned regex, I was told that everything that wasn't a number or a letter could have special meaning.   Even if it doesn't now, it might in a future version, so it is better to escape them.  Is this not true?

Is there a list of characters I shouldn't escape for Firefox?

Comment: _sidenote_ :- you don't need to escape those characters in character class as they don't have any special meaning

Answer (score 13):

This is due to the following change: [Bug 1227906 - HTML `pattern` attribute should set `u` flag for regular expressions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1227906)

As someone has already said, you don't have to escape those characters. Just use:

```
<input pattern="[@%]">
```

Comment: Posted the [site compatibility doc](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/input-pattern-now-sets-u-flag-for-regular-expressions/) for this.

Comment: The [related github issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/439) has also now been reopened.

Comment: Any idea why you can't escape those characters in Unicode regex mode?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It’s [not necessary](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#impact-syntax) to escape them, so why would you? The reason unnecessary escapes throw in `u` mode is so that the spec can later assign a special meaning to some of them, such as `\p` and `\P`. That would be a backwards-incompatible change if `\p` were equivalent to just `p`.

Comment: Escaped numbers and letters are reserved for special use, but my understanding is that all symbols are reserved for future use unescaped.

Comment: One reason to add extra escapes is because simple regex escaping utilities add it, and to date that has been safe.