# Can some one help me fix this regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

> Pattern attribute value ^[-\w\.\$@\*\!]{1,30}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[-\w\.\$@\*\!]{1,30}$/: Invalid escape

I am using like this in angular.

```html
 <input pattern='^[-\w\.\$@\*\!]{1,30}$' />
```

Comment: It would be great if you tell more about this. What are you trying to accomplish and what you tried. If you need to test the regex try [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Comment: I am getting this error in console when i am entering something in username field.There are username regex out there but i just want to know what is the error in this expression.Is it not following any rules?

Comment: Works for me, I don't get any errors when I run the snippet. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Toto — It errors when I test it in Chrome.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox error: Unable to check input because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953775/firefox-error-unable-to-check-input-because-the-pattern-is-not-a-valid-regexp)

Comment: It will throuw an error on Firefox as well

Comment: @Naveen Look at my answer. I've added some detail about the cause for this issue

Comment: @yunzen: It works with Firefox 65.0.2 (64bit)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why (speculation: Bug in Chrome) but removing the escape before the exclamation mark resolves the problem when I test it.

Inside a `[...]` group, `\!` and `!` are equivalent.

```html
 <input pattern='^[-\w\.\$@\*!]{1,30}$' />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you `Invalid escape` (Chrome) or `invalid identity escape in regular expression` (Firefox). So one or more of your escapes (`"\<any-character>"`) is not right.

I removed every backslash from your Regex except for the `\w`. Those are not needed, because you only need to escape characters that are special characters. As your RegEx mainly consists of a [character class](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#classes) only special characters in character classes need to be escaped. `.`, `$`, `*`, `!` are not special characters in character classes. And the `-` is not a special character, if it doesn't come first (or second after a `^`).

```css
input {
  border: 2px solid;
}

input:valid {
  border-color: green;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
With escaped <code>!<code> => <code>^[-\w.$@*\!]{1,30}</code><br>
<input pattern="^[-\w.$@*\!]{1,30}$" value="a" /> Should be valid, but throws error<br>
<input pattern="^[-\w.$@*\!]{1,30}$" value="a a " /> Should be invalid, but throws error<br>
<input pattern="^[-\w.$@*\!]{1,30}$" value="a!@@$-!...@" /> Should be valid, but throws error<br>
<br>
Without escaped <code>!<code> => <code>^[-\w.$@*!]{1,30}</code><br>
<input pattern="^[-\w.$@*!]{1,30}$" value="a" /> Should be valid<br>
<input pattern="^[-\w.$@*!]{1,30}$" value="a a " /> Should be invalid<br>
<input pattern="^[-\w.$@*!]{1,30}$" value="a!@@$-!...@" /> Should be valid<br>
```

#### Explanation

The `pattern` always sets the `u` flag for the RegEx. `u` here means Unicode.
From: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#impact-html

> The <kbd>u</kbd> flag is always enabled for regular expressions compiled through the HTML `pattern` attribute. Here’s a [demo / test case](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/pattern-u).

But the Unicode flag will only allow reserved escape sequences, and `\!` is not one of those as `!` is never a special character.

From: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#impact-syntax

> things like `\a` (where `a` is not an escape character) won’t be equivalent to `a` anymore. So even though `/\a/` is treated as `/a/`, `/\a/u` throws an error, because `\a` is not a reserved escape sequence.

P.S.: Microsoft Edge browser does seem to be Unicode capable, as this code will throw an error `/\!/u`, even with the best and most telling error message of all the browsers: "invalid escape in unicode pattern", but it does not seem the set the unicode flag on `pattern` attributes.