# Regex for all strings that contain exactly two occurrences of 'aa'?

Tags: regex

This is a simple question of the Theory of Computation.
I don't know nor want the python coded interpretation of this but rather the theoretical answer of the expression. 
I have tried my best to figure it out and came up with the below code:

```
 (ab+ba+bb)*. aa.(ab+ba+bb)*.aa.(ab+ba+bb)* + b*.aa.b*.aa.b*
```

Is it right? Am I forgetting any other case?

Comment: Your sample looks weird. Should this be two regex patterns left and right of the `+` rightmost? Also the use of [unescaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-to-regex) `.` is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is too complicated and not very flexible (it only works with strings of a and b). A better solution uses negative look-ahead assertions:

```
^(?:(?!aa).)*aa(?:(?!aa).)*aa(?:(?!aa).)*$
```

This looks for any length of substring at the start of the string that does not contain `aa`, then the first `aa`, and so on.

Comment: A possible simplification: `^(?:(?:(?!aa).)*aa){2}(?:(?!aa).)*$` http://regexr.com/3v54r

Comment: I don't want the python(coding) version of this. I'm simply a student who wants to know the regular expression that accepts the problem in hand. Also, my set of symbols is {a, b}.

Comment: @MeghnaTanwal My answer isn’t limited to Python. It should solve your problem. If it helped you, please remember to accept it.