# Extract string enclosed by parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

```
“test+IF(one,2,2)+Wow+IF(two,1,1)”
```

I need to get the following strings:

```
IF(one,2,2)
IF(two,1,1)
```

I tried the following regex but it only gives me the following with missing close parenthesis

```
Pattern pattern.compile(“IF(([^)]+))”);
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(formula);
While(matcehr.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Result is

```
IF(one,2,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code achieves your desired result:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String formula = "test+IF(one,2,2)+Wow+IF(two,1,1)";
        java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("IF\\(.*?\\)");
        java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formula);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

The regular expression is the literal string `IF` followed by a (literal) opening parenthesis (i.e. `(`) followed by zero or more characters. The question mark is a reluctant qualifier which means that the string of any characters will be terminated by the first closing parenthesis encountered. Refer to this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bc8Ohe/1) and this [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/w4R) as well as the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for class `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
IF(one,2,2)
IF(two,1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the parenthesis.

```
IF(\([^)]+\))
```

With this, it should work.
You will find a list of characters that need to be escaped (though there it is for javasript) in a regex here: [List of all characters that should be escaped before put in to RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105143/list-of-all-characters-that-should-be-escaped-before-put-in-to-regex)
In summary, generally, you should escape these characters: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`